# Linq2Db Async Insert - Cannot access a disposed object. ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name'

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, asp.net5, linq2db

I have been working on my own project that I have been using .Net Core 3.1 and Linq2b ORM tool for. I have a problem that is about inserting data by using async metot. I want to insert **a log data.** There is a method that is called **InsertWithInt32IdentityAsync** in Linq2Db. This method returns an error that is called **Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: IServiceProvider**.

Here is the implementations.

```
    [HttpPost("createpost")]
    [Authorize]
    public virtual async Task<JsonResult> CreatePost([FromForm] PostCreateApi model)
    {
        var serviceResponse = _postService.Create(model);

        if (serviceResponse.Warnings.Count > 0 || serviceResponse.Warnings.Any())
            return BadResponse(new ResultModel
            {
                Status = false,
                Message = serviceResponse.Warnings.First()
            });
        
        //Here returns an error
        await _logService.InsertLogAsync(Domain.Enumerations.LogLevel.Information, $"PostsController- Create Post Request", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));

        return OkResponse(new PostListDto
        {
            Id = serviceResponse.Data.Id,
            Text = serviceResponse.Data?.Text,
            ImageUrl = serviceResponse.Data.ImageUrl?.ToString(),
            CreatedByUserName = serviceResponse.Data?.CreatedByUserName,
            CreatedByUserPhoto = serviceResponse.Data?.CreatedByUserPhoto,
            CreatedDate = serviceResponse.Data.CreatedDate,
            VideoUrl = serviceResponse.Data?.VideoUrl,
            PostType = serviceResponse.Data?.PostType,
            Comments = null
        });
    }
```

Here is **InsertLogAsync** method.

```
 public virtual async Task<Log> InsertLogAsync(LogLevel logLevel, string shortMessage, string fullMessage = "", AppUser appUser = null)
    {
        var log = new Log
        {
            LogLevel = logLevel,
            ShortMessage = shortMessage,
            FullMessage = fullMessage,
            IpAddress = _webHelper.GetCurrentIpAddress(),
            CustomerId = appUser?.Id,
            PageUrl = _webHelper.GetThisPageUrl(true),
            ReferrerUrl = _webHelper.GetUrlReferrer(),
            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        await _logRepository.InsertAsync(log);

        return log;
    }
```

Here is BaseDataProvider **InsertEntityAsync** method.

```
  public virtual async Task<TEntity> InsertEntityAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : 
  BaseEntity
    {
        using var dataContext = CreateDataConnection();
        entity.Id = await dataContext.InsertWithInt32IdentityAsync(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

Here is **StackTrace**.

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at FluentMigrator.Infrastructure.MigrationContext..ctor(IQuerySchema querySchema, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Object context, String connection)
at DevPlatform.Data.Migrations.MigrationManager.CreateNullMigrationContext() in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Migrations\MigrationManager.cs:line 165
at DevPlatform.Data.Migrations.MigrationManager.GetCreateTableExpression(Type type) in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Migrations\MigrationManager.cs:line 240
at DevPlatform.Data.Mapping.FluentMigratorMetadataReader.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<GetAttribute>b__1(Type entityType) in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Mapping\FluentMigratorMetadataReader.cs:line 42 at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) at DevPlatform.Data.Mapping.FluentMigratorMetadataReader.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.b__0(ValueTuple`2 t) in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Mapping\FluentMigratorMetadataReader.cs:line 42 at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) at DevPlatform.Data.Mapping.FluentMigratorMetadataReader.GetAttribute[T](Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo) in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Mapping\FluentMigratorMetadataReader.cs:line 40 at DevPlatform.Data.Mapping.FluentMigratorMetadataReader.GetAttributes[T](Type type, Type attributeType, MemberInfo memberInfo) in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Mapping\FluentMigratorMetadataReader.cs:line 76 at DevPlatform.Data.Mapping.FluentMigratorMetadataReader.GetAttributes[T](Type type, Boolean inherit) in C:\Projects\DevPlatform\DevPlatform.Data\Mapping\FluentMigratorMetadataReader.cs:line 97 at LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.<>c__DisplayClass51_0`1.b__0(IMetadataReader mr)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__181`3.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items) at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
at LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.GetAttributes[T](Type type, Boolean inherit)
at LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.GetAttributes[T](Type type, Func`2 configGetter, Boolean inherit, Boolean exactForConfiguration) at LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.GetAttribute[T](Type type, Func`2 configGetter, Boolean inherit)
at LinqToDB.Mapping.EntityDescriptor.Init()
at LinqToDB.Mapping.EntityDescriptor..ctor(MappingSchema mappingSchema, Type type)
at LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.<>c.b__92_0(ICacheEntry o, <>f__AnonymousType131`2 key, MappingSchema context) at LinqToDB.Common.Internal.Cache.CacheExtensions.GetOrCreate[TItem,TKey,TContext](IMemoryCache cache, TKey key, TContext context, Func`4 factory)
at LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.GetEntityDescriptor(Type type)
at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.GetType[T](T obj, IDataContext db)
at LinqToDB.Linq.QueryRunner.InsertWithIdentity`1.d__2.MoveNext()

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are at least two situations when it fails. You have disposed DataConnection in IOC container and trying to run query. Or you have missed `await` in other place. Also provide full stack trace,

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have just added stack trace.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I have just added stack trace. You can see above.

Comment: Your MigrationManager is capturing a MigrationContext as a field and trying to use its ServiceProvider when creating a "null" MigrationContext. That ServiceProvider looks like it was already disposed by that point. You could look into the lifecycles in your dependency injection configuration, but you should probably reconsider how you're constructing that MigrationContext in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by editing **CreateTableExpressionBuilder** and calling _migrationContext instead of calling CreateNullMigrationContext function.

Instead of the following code block;

```
    public virtual CreateTableExpression GetCreateTableExpression(Type type)
    {
        var expression = new CreateTableExpression { TableName = NameCompatibilityManager.GetTableName(type) };
        var builder = new CreateTableExpressionBuilder(expression, CreateNullMigrationContext());

        RetrieveTableExpressions(type, builder);

        return builder.Expression;
    }
```

I have changed **CreateTableExpressionBuilder** for this problem.

```
 public virtual CreateTableExpression GetCreateTableExpression(Type type)
    {
        var expression = new CreateTableExpression { TableName = NameCompatibilityManager.GetTableName(type) };
        var builder = new CreateTableExpressionBuilder(expression, _migrationContext);

        RetrieveTableExpressions(type, builder);

        return builder.Expression;
    }
```

**CreateNullMigrationContext** function returns an error as I have mentioned about it.

```
 protected IMigrationContext CreateNullMigrationContext()
    {
        return new MigrationContext(new NullIfDatabaseProcessor(), 
          _migrationContext.ServiceProvider, null, null);
    }
```

Thank you very much. @StriplingWarrior, @Paulo Morgado and @Svyatoslav Danyliv